# Mobx state tree nested stores injection

Tags: reactjs, mobx-state-tree

I have one issue using mobx-state-tree.
If we have nested stores with following structure

```
login(store):{
    //some primitives
},
mainPage(store):{
    slider:(store):{
        //some primitives
    },
    userList:(store):{
        //some primitives
    },
    //some primitives
},
```

How we can inject just `userList` store.
I tried to do like this:

```
@inject('mainPage.userList')
```

But it throws an error

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: MobX injector: Store 'mainPage.userList' is not available!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject a sub store directly without having a direct reference to it. You could simply inject the mainPage then access it in the constructor.

```
@inject('mainPage')
```

then

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.userList = this.props.mainPage.userList
}
```

One improvement would be to have a rootStore and only inject that to each component via a providor. This simplifies testing and each component can have access to the whole tree.

Take a look at the getting started docs and you can see various examples of using a rootStore:

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md